# Any ideas on how to make a UIPickerView from scratch?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uipickerview

I've decided that I don't want to ever use UIPickerView again... it's completely inflexible in terms of functionality, design, and size (height). It also occasionally gets stuck between rows, and the delay that occurs between letting go of a wheel and when the delegate method is fired indicating that a new row has been selected (because of the "settling in" animation) has caused lots of problems in the context of the apps I've been working on.

That being said, the user-friendly aspects of UIPickerView are good, and I'd like to try to replicate it. I've tried to research different ways that this might be done, but without much success. Does anyone have any ideas as to what would be involved to make something similar from scratch?

I was trying to get a UITableView subclass to behave in such a way that whatever cell was currently in the middle of the table (it would change while dragging, etc.) would change its background colour to something different implying that it was "selected". As soon as the table was dragged such that the "selected" cell was no longer in the middle, the cell would go back to normal and the new middle cell would change colour. So this would be like UIPickerView in a sense that you don't have to tap on a cell; instead you just drag to have one selected by default.

I figured it should have been easy enough to intercept the "touchesMoved" method of UITableView and add some code that looped through all currently viewable cells in the table, checking to see if their frames overlapped the center point of the table, and changing their appearance accordingly (plus sending a notification to other classes as needed to indicate the "selection" change). Unfortunately, I can't get this to work, as the "touchesMoved" method doesn't get called when I drag the table. Am I missing something obvious?

Any ideas or suggestions would be very much appreciated at this point... I made an app that relied heavily on UIPickerView objects, and because of the problems I've run into with them, I'll have to abandon it unless I can figure out a way to make this work.

Thanks very much,

Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that a UITableView is a subclass of a UIScrollView, and the UITableViewDelegate gets all the UIScrollViewDelegate method calls too. `scrollViewDidScroll:` sounds like it would easily fit the bill for knowing when the table view was scrolled.

As for finding which row is in the middle of the view, just use `indexPathForRowAtPoint:`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. With those two methods, this will be much simpler than I had originally made it out to be... thanks for the help... very much appreciated!

Comment: Sure enough, your suggestions worked great. I've got everything more or less set up now (including delegate methods that are fired when a new cell moves to the center of the table), but my custom UITableView is still lacking one fundamental aspect of the UIPickerView, which is that if you choose the top or bottom rows, they should center vertically within the table (even if that means empty space occupying some of the table). I've looked at documentation for UIScrollView and UITableView, with no luck. Any ideas if this is relatively easy to do?

Comment: @chrisb: Try setting an appropriate top and bottom insets for `contentInset`

Comment: Once again, you've provided exactly the thing I was looking for. I hope to one day be as intuitive with finding the appropriate methods in the Apple documentation… in the meanwhile, thanks for helping me out. In case anyone else is ever trying to achieve this effect, I made it work by simply setting both the top and bottom elements of the table's UIEdgeInsets to '(tableView.frame.size.height / 2) - ([tableView rowHeight] / 2)' to imitate the same scrolling appearance as the UIPickerView.

Comment: Great answers... How did you get around the problem of snapping to a cell? I've been waiting for scrollViewDidEndDecelerating: and followed it with setContentOffset:animated: to snap it to the nearest cell which works but isn't perfect... Any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever find out a solid solution to snapping to a cell? I would love to get some ideas on how to accomplish that!

Comment: @chrisb did you ever figure out how to find the middle row. using "indexPathForRowAtPoint:"

Comment: @RyanCodes to get the middle row, in your `UIViewController` that has a `tableView`:

let center = view.convert(view.center, to: tableView) then
let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: center) then
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) // middle cell